# Как замедлить скроллинг?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Данный код имеет якорь. Как замедлить скроллинг?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tpls = ['1.php', '2.php', '3.php', '4.php', ];

  $('.loadBtn').click(function() {
    loadContent($(this).index());
  });
  loadContent(0);

  function loadContent(index) {
    if (!tpls[index]) return;
    $.ajax({
      url: tpls[index],
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#content").html(html);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="loadBtn" value="1"><a href="#top">1</a></li>
<li class="loadBtn" value="2"><a href="#top">2</a></li>
<li class="loadBtn" value="3"><a href="#top">3</a></li>
<li class="loadBtn" value="4"><a href="#top">4</a></li>

<div id="content">
  <a name="top" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз используете `jquery` у него есть метод `animate` - и свойство `scrollTop`, через `click` обработать `a` и берем аттрибут `href`, где `#якорь` - это ид нужного нам блока, берем у него `$('#якорь').offset().top` и через `animate` скроллим.

```
$('.loadBtn a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1000);
});
```

А также есть плагин `.scrollTo` который переходит к нужному элементу.
Плагин нужно скачать и подключить.

```
$('.loadBtn a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.scrollTo($($(this).attr('href')), 1000);
});
```

Если требуется выставлять якоря в адресную строку, воспользоваться `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 2):

В моём примере два кода jquery

1) делает плавную прокрутку до якоря

2) фиксирует меню при скролле до якоря

Описание работы первого скрипта jquery дал пользователь [And](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/643075/33274)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
    event.preventDefault();

    //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),

      //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
      top = $(id).offset().top;

    //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  body = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (body > 200) {
    $("#menu").addClass('back');
  } else {
    $("#menu").removeClass('back');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.link {
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee, #ddd);
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}

.c {
  background: green;
}

.back {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0!important;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .5);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">

  <li class="link"><a href="#a">Блок А</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="#b">Блок Б</a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="#c">Блок С</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="a" class="a"></div>
<div id="b" class="b"></div>
<div id="c" class="c"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```